# 3D sphere with a hole volume

Tags: calculus, integration

I am currently studying Calculus 3.
I need to calculate the volume of 3D sphere with radius $r$ and with a hole.
The hole's diameter is $r$ from the sphere and it's locating between sphere center and sphere edge.

Is there any formula for this question?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean this one? https://youtu.be/J51ncHP_BrY

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997230/volume-of-a-sphere-with-cylinder-in-the-middle/3997484#3997484

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volume of a Sphere with Cylinder in the Middle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997230/volume-of-a-sphere-with-cylinder-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what you mean, but lets say what you want is this (if it's not, ignore this answer)

[image: This is the model of the sphere]

This PDF is great for answering your question. Click here to access it. [http://www.sfu.ca/~adebened/funstuff/sphere_cyl.pdf](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Eadebened/funstuff/sphere_cyl.pdf)

Basically if you want to skip all the Math Jargon in the PDF, the volume is calculated by:

$$V = \frac{4}{3}\pi h^3$$

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: the center hole is about t_0 offset to the right, and t_0 is equal to R/2,   thank  :-)